# How Do I disable the button if the toggle-slide is set false(off state) and enable when the toggle-slide is clicked Using Angular?

Tags: angular, toggle, submit-button

Currently, I have a modal popup that has various fields, including dropdown lists . The submit button is enabled  when either of these fields is selected or populated. I have recently added a slide-toggle to the modal. This is set in 'false' state by default. I want the submit button to be enabled even if I slide the toggle?

Current scenario: Submit button is enabled  if I select any of  the other fields (excluding the Slide-toggle).

Comment: Have no idea what you have implemented, you at least need to post minimum effort/code you have done so far and where you are stuck then anyone can rescue you. This is how stackoverflow community helps you are new note it this might help you.

Comment: Noted! Thank you.